# I want to pass fetch data into my reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Playing around with fetch data in an async action in redux and using a reducer. Just need some help fetching the data into the reducer. Below is what i have so far.

**actions.js**

```js
function receiveData(loadData) {
  return {
    type: 'RECEIVE_POSTS',
    loadData
  };
}

function schemaData(loadData) {
  return dispatch => {
    return fetch(`www.fetchurlhere`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => dispatch(schemaData(loadData, response.data)));
  };
}
```

**reducer.js**

```js
export default function schemaData(prevState = {}, action) {
  if (action.type === 'RECEIVE_POSTS') {
    return action.receiveData;
  } else {
    return prevState;
  }
}
```

I can see the reducer 'schemaData' in the store but its empty. Never requested a fetch in an action before. I have had a look at the redux example and tried to modify for mine. But its empty so something is missing.

Comment: Have you setup `redux-thunk`? And have you looked at what's getting fired etc?

Comment: Yes have you had setup redux-thunk and then share the middleware composition of store. i.e. store.js . And pass key `recieveData` and to its value `loadData` in schemaData function

Comment: yup think this is all correct and working. Just gives me a blank reducer in the store.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

---

*actions.js*

```js
function receiveData(loadData) {
  return {
    type: 'RECEIVE_POSTS',
    receiveData: loadData
  };
}

function schemaData() {
  return dispatch => {
    return fetch(`www.fetchurlhere`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => dispatch(receiveData(json)));
  };
}
```

---

*reducer.js*

```js
export default function schemaData(prevState = {}, action) {
  if (action.type === 'RECEIVE_POSTS') {
    return action.receiveData;
  } else {
    return prevState;
  }
}
```

---

This is a small demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/3vmn3lvp76

Comment: No sorry that didn't work, still get an empty reducer in the store. Thanks though.

Comment: I've made a small demo for you

Comment: Check the demo @NguyễnThanhTú has created!

Comment: I get Uncaught ReferenceError: schemaData is not defined.

Comment: @NguyễnThanhTú Thank you so much for the example. I have the action and reducer exactly the same but when i use redux devtools and check my store 'schemaData' reducer is still empty. I just want this fetch request to populate the reducer so its in the store.